# Magento 2: How to setup ReCaptcha on Registration form and forgot password form?

Tags: magento2, customer-account, captcha, create

Anyone know the best method to activate ReCaptcha on Customer registration form? and Forgot Password form? any plugin or any class snippet can help?

Comment: Check https://ranasohel.me/2016/07/06/how-to-integrate-recaptcha-in-magento-2-contact-page/

Comment: [ReCaptcha Plugin](https://github.com/karliuka/m2.ReCaptcha)

Comment: https://magecomp.com/magento-2-google-recaptcha.html